# What's the advantage of interacting with a smart contract from another smart contract (instead of just calling it using something like Web3.js)?

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, ethers.js, uniswap

I've noticed there are lots of tutorials online that talk about deploying a smart contract that allows them to interact with other smart contracts e.g. deploying a smart contract to interact with Uniswap's contracts here: https://soliditydeveloper.com/uniswap2

Is there any advantage of deploying a smart contract to call Uniswap's contract functions vs. calling those functions directly using something like ethersjs or Web3js?

Seems like a lot of extra hassle having to deploy a smart contract first.

Comment: The advantage is the ability to perform several function-calls as a single (atomic) transaction.

Comment: Good point. I hadn't considered that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advantage of executing a sequence of operations in a smart contract constructor rather than from an off-chain script (web3.js for example), is the ability to perform these operations within a single atomic transaction, which ensures that no other operation (executed by someone else) gets in between.

Answer (score 0):

A Smart Contract is decentralized. Meaning anybody can execute it and it will run. When you execute your contract from web3, you have to do it manually and setup some javascript code while in a Smart Contract you just call the other Smart Contract and it will work.